# Why am I allowed to delete moderator-only tags?

Tags: bug, status-completed, rollbacks, moderator-tags

One would think only a moderator should be able to mess with moderator tags.

**P.S.**: I was also able to reapply it during a rollback.  So, actually I was able to both delete and *apply* a moderator tag.

**3**: Again, I rolled it back.  It's no longer tagged "status-completed".  Not trying to be an effer here, just don't think I should be allowed to do that.

Comment: I don't think reapplying it via a rollback is that big of an issue, since it had to be initially applied by a moderator.

Comment: I just thought I'd mention it.  If a mod removes a mod tag, I should not be able to reapply it with a rollback.

Comment: It's witchery what this rollback loop-hole is! @jon

Comment: Well, at least if we discover that something isn't actually complete, we can annoy Jeff to fix it by continually rolling back the `[status-completed]` tag. ;) @random

Comment: Is this question getting to be the town bike?

Comment: meta deployed ... roll back this tag if you can :)

Comment: @JonSeigel: That use case is rather singular ;-P.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just fixed this old, old, old bug.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to. Seems like a bug. I think it's intentional that non-moderators are not able to add them. I just would think that a non-moderator shouldn't be able to remove them as well. I believe the whole point is for moderators only to be able to provide status of feature requests and bugs.

Comment: But I could not ADD a moderator only tag. I feel like that's persecuting the under-priviledged.

Comment: Well whatddya know.  Yea that seems like a bug.

Comment: @devinb: kinda the point, yes...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's actually by (accidental) design - if that makes any sense.

On uservoice, users were able to re-open a ticket.  It just wasn't obvious how, or even that it was possible.  From the users' perspective closed tickets tended to just disappear, even though the url was still good.

Comment: this is not by design

Comment: Ha.  Good guess though Joel.