# Allow rel="me" in stackoverflow profile HTML

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, hyperlinks, profile-page

On the user profile page you can put [basic HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed)

In particular:

> The following attributes are allowed on the `<a>` tag:
>
> ```
> href=""  
> title=""
> ```

It would be nice if I could add a `rel` attribute and value of `"me"` on the links in that basic HTML box as well to adhere to [this microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-me) which [stackoverflow already uses](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/12/microformats-boon-or-bane.html) itself in the Website field.  But I have more than one link which represents me which I'd like to describe properly in my description box.

Example:

```
<li><a href="http://www.brianbondy.com rel="me">My website</a></li>
<li><a href="http://twitter.com/brianbondy" rel="me">@brianbondy</a></li>
<!-- Et cetera -->
```

Currently it will deactivate the link if I try to add `rel="me"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is more involved, I'm putting it as an answer even though it's in support of the original idea.

I realize that the links in the "about me" box are nofollowed. This is often understood to mean that they are only for real people browsing, and that search engines are supposed to ignore them. What it really means (at least according to google) is that your site doesn't vouch for the content at the other end of the link. It still may get crawled, and may get used in ways that don't affect your site.

I realize that my "website" link has the property, and is not nofollowed.

The reason I would like to be able to use `rel=me` in my profile is a bit complicated. I link to SO from a number of different profile sites (most of which are dofollow), all using `rel=me`. Because anyone can link to any site with that attribute, crawlers know that both ends of a link should be validated before they can count a profile as confirmed to belong to the "me" that the web of other profiles create.

Unfortunately, not all crawlers are perfect, and sometimes miss pages or simply aren't interested in crawling an entire network of profiles. There are user agents who simply look for the 2-way "this page links to that with `rel=me`, that page links to this with `rel=me`". In those cases, being unable to link to more than one page means that my SO profile must stagnate as a leaf rather than as an interconnected web.

I'm not asking you to change the nofollow policy. Just allow us to add `rel=me` so we can confirm ownership of our profile in the context of multiple inbound `rel=me` links.

Answer (score -4):

This attribute is already added to the "website" field of your profile.

This field is also un-nofollowed at 2k rep.

Comment: This technically doesn't address his request.  He states in his question that the website link already uses `rel=me`, but he wants to be able to add more than one `rel=me` link.

Comment: So, my suggestion is that you mark this status declined if you don't plan on changing it, or status review/planned if you do plan on changing it.

Comment: @justin - `status-bydesign`

Comment: @Gnoupi, yea..or that.

Comment: not-nofollowed at 2k rep

Comment: @Jeff: I don't think you understood my feature request.   In my feature request I mentioned what you stated in your post about the website link already having it.  My request was to allow basic HTML in  the description to have the right to add a `rel="me"` attribute to the HTML `a` element.  Could you re-read?  It is not `status-bydesign` but perhaps `status-declined` because the feature I'm  talking about is not addressed.

Comment: why lock it? just curious

Comment: @Juan: Because of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/why-am-i-allowed-to-delete-moderator-only-tags) and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/57651/revisions).

Comment: @Juan: I think I overstepped my boundaries by reverting the status which I felt was wrong based on the answer which didn't match my question.

Comment: My -1 is not because of the status-declined, but because the answer doesn't address the question still.  I will revert the -1 though if you write an answer to match the question.

Comment: @Jeff: I posted another answer in support of the idea, I'd appreciate your input.