# Why can't I have an <a rel="external me" href="…">hyper link</a> in my profiler @ StEx?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, design, network-profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow rel=“me” in stackoverflow profile HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57651/allow-rel-me-in-stackoverflow-profile-html)

I tried to have this code in my profile:

```
<a href="http://knarf.se/" rel="external me">Ego-Hub</a>
```

I got de-tagged, why can't i have a such tag?

The `rel`-attribute says that the link is external, and that you (or I, depending on viewpoint) says that the link should be treated as.

That attribute also say s that it is a page 'bout me.

I guess this can't be seen as a bug, but more of a low-prio feature request, I guess.

---

**Okay**, so my link that already is on my profile is marked as `rel="nofollow me"` -- *So **why** is that **not** mentioned anywhere?* (I just checked the source of my profile-page here at meta)

And the `nofollow`-thing goes into thin air when one have 2ĸ -- Why ain't that not mentioned? That is kind of very strong incentive to why one should be active here and be a good girl/boy/hen/whatever one prefers to be referred to; And provide good answers to others questions.

**Still**, I *would like to have two `rel="external me"` to both **github** and **panaramio**.*

And quite possibly to google-profile too (Even if it's connected to my old mail, use regular gmail and not their buissniess-version, as it is not very well supported -- I can for example still not get an Google+ account)...

I guess that *you* can guess that I'm **not** linking back to any StEx-sites (Even if that would be beneficial to me, to get a completely interconnected nest around me on the web); At least not until i hit 2k at some of the sites.

And I would say that my question is still not answered, So I asks it again but with less fuzz, and rephrasing:

Why can I not have a link that says **exactly** the following on my StackExchange-profile:

```
<a href="http://knarf.se/about" rel="external me">About me</a>
```

Comment: What the hell happened to all your letters?

Comment: What the heck do you mean (excuse wording)? Can't you view UTF-8/Unicode letters, or is it something else?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55842/no-follow-attribute-set-in-user-profile-website-link-why