# Users without enough reputation to retag can remove moderator-only tags

Tags: bug, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I allowed to delete moderator-only tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/why-am-i-allowed-to-delete-moderator-only-tags)

See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/240; the user removed [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: you mean `status-completed`?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: This is not a dupe, is it?

Comment: @Pekka:  It's the precise same issue. The edit suggestion was based on a previous revision, making it essentially a rollback.

Comment: @balpha ah, okay.