# Anonymous user can suggest moderator tags, because he is Community ♦?

Tags: bug, moderator-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Users without enough reputation to retag can remove moderator-only tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81680/users-without-enough-reputation-to-retag-can-remove-moderator-only-tags)

https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/7322/revisions

[image]

Comment: Intentionally closing as a dupe of a dupe, since it's the *precise* same thing (rollback via suggested edit)

Comment: So being "Community" has nothing to do with it, anybody can change the tags with a rollback?

Comment: @Gabe: Yes - I did that once with one of my questions, but it resulted in another rollback and the post being locked ...