# Suggested edits can remove moderator-only tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, suggested-edits

I just approved a suggested edit on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/230242/revisions). Presumably, the edit was started before Oded added [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), and so the suggested edit was submitted without that tag. This is a regression of a [formerly-fixed bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81680/users-without-enough-reputation-to-retag-can-remove-moderator-only-tags?rq=1).

Comment: Looks like it's time to get some edits going for the [highest voted status-declined posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined?sort=votes&pageSize=15) and *change the course of history!*

Comment: Yup. I started the edit before the tag was added, but submitted it immediately after I saw an edit had been made (didn't check what the edit was). I take it you didn't have the option to revert the inadvertent removal of the new tag because only mods can add it?  BTW, you link to a duplicate of [Why am I allowed to delete moderator-only tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6368/246931), which got the actual [tag:status-completed] tag.

Comment: Reproduced. The case where the user adds a suggested edit _before_ a protected tag added via an edit is handled, but the other way around (employee ads status-* tag, while the user already has the edit UI open) it's not.

Answer (score 7):

The fix implemented in the past only of the case where a user *won* the re-tagging race against a mod. For that to happen we the mod had to open the edit UI before the (suggested) edit was save. However, it did not take care of the case where the order of events was reversed.

Now, whenever there a normal user tries to save a (suggest or full) edit, and there is a new revision which has mod-only tags (whereas the revision the user is editing hasn't), the user will get an error message prompting him to apply his edits to the latest revision. Unfortunately this requires reloading of the page. Luckily though, this is merely enforcing users to act as suggested in the realtime notification on top they already see.

The described fix will roll out with build rev `2014.4.23.2183` on meta and `2014.4.23.1563` on sites.

Comment: Is the approval by non-moderators of [this suggested edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/27918) that added a moderator-only tag, related?

Comment: @Arjan [It's already documented that non-diamond employees can suggest edits to red tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193587/223030), and there seems to be nothing against approval of those suggested edits.