# The Denver office violates the trademark guidance

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, trademark

According to [Stack Exchange's trademark guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance):

> The website domain name is always written stackoverflow.com (no CamelCase, single word capitalization rules apply).

However in the semi-recent Server Fault blog post, [Welcome Shane Madden, ServerFault Valued Associate #0000007!](http://blog.serverfault.com/2014/04/23/welcome-serverfault-valued-associate-0000007/), there's a picture, which implies it hasn't been followed by... Stack Exchange!

[image: Oops]

I don't think that "Expert" needs to be capitalised either<sup>1</sup>

<sub>1. I know, [giant S](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105), please don't kill me.</sub>

Comment: The change to the window will be pushed in the next build.

Comment: Needs moar backticks.

Comment: Similar violation [*in* the New York office](https://www.google.com/maps/@40.708719,-74.006946,3a,75y,120.3h,78.14t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1sPe4cJnk1dBYAAAGusWN7aA!2e0!3e2), as for the lacking space in the name Stack Exchange. (No, I don't buy it's the logo, as I don't see any blue nor bold in that text!)

Comment: We've made a huge mistake.

Comment: At least in the NY office it's easily solved, @Kasra. Switch off those beamers—they're not making the internet a better place, are they? ;-)

Comment: I'm causing problems! We should definitely fix that in the next build (new Denver office coming up).

Comment: Not sure how appropriate it is for me to do so, but I've approved your edit @shane :-).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Heh, I'm a little surprised that worked!

Comment: Indeed, Shane & @ben -- I've pinged m0sa about that [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230245/suggested-edits-can-remove-moderator-only-tags/230337#comment764722_230337).

Comment: @Arjan Might be different in this case as I have the sysadmin flag on my account, not sure how that is interacting with the edit process.

Comment: What, @Shane, no shiny diamond for that flag? ;-) (Feel free to delete my comment to m0sa, if not applicable. And if you can!)

Comment: (@Shane, meanwhile someone responded to my comment there. You're right.)

Comment: @Oded picture or it never happened. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - they moved to a new office...

Comment: @Oded cheers, but how can we know they did not copy the door with the same horrible violation?

Comment: Tell you what, I'll be there in October - will take some photos for you then ;) @sha

Comment: @Oded thanks, hope to remember to remind you! ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard copy/paste doesn't work as well IRL...

Comment: @enderland easy enough with 3D printers. ;-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In answer, I give you a glimpse into the secret world of our company chat:

[image]

So, in other words, it's fixed in the next build.

**Update:** by now (July 24<sup>th</sup> 2014) they [moved to a new office](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232216/the-denver-office-violates-the-trademark-guidance?noredirect=1#comment777060_232216) leaving the bug behind.

Comment: Finally... now we know where Joel lurks. :-)

Comment: That's beautiful!

Comment: So what you're saying is... I did it!

Comment: Now I'm going to need to at least find a red dry-erase marker next time I'm in the office.

Comment: Fixed in the next building, then.

Comment: Just curious: what do you call the company chat room? :) "We ♥ Atwood?"

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin The main room is just called "Joel's Room"