# The SO logo on the wall of whatever room in your castles is not updated

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, caching, logo

So, in [this recent blog post](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/07/how-we-built-our-blog) I can see that the logo on the wall is the old one:

> [image]

Yeah, this logo was valid until SO was SVGified. However, after SVGifation, the logo has changed:

> [image]

Shouldn't the wall reflect the new logo, or possibly it's just caching (though the change has occurred quite a long time ago)?

Comment: Wut the heck is this? Caching? I'm done

Comment: @Uni Actually, I don't know: "*possibly* it's just caching"

Comment: Hmm, it must be Friday ...

Comment: @Bart o.0 and I have holidays, so I didn't notice!

Comment: status-bydesign? You guys __put__ bugs on the wall and want us to stare at it not being able to do anything? Why?

Comment: Do I see an unicorn on that cushion?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist good catch! Have it for dinner!

Comment: @UniKitty O.O Are you suggesting to EAT UNICORNS?!

Comment: Just look at my profile picture :P

Comment: @Uni :O *runs away in horror*

Comment: One of the more silly bug reports, but voted to reopen.

Comment: @Sha Ummm, do you really think it should be reopened? It was kind of fun bug report, but it really doesn't pertain to the SE *software*, which I haven't realized at first and voted to reopen also.

Comment: @nicael MSE can be used to discuss anything about Stack Exchange as far as I can tell, not just software. I might be wrong, but that's my opinion. :-)

Comment: @Sha okay then!

Comment: @Sha And also, I can't count how many Reversals my questions have generated :D

Comment: I'm not going to vote to reopen, even though I don't mind the bug report, it's just that what's next, that the logo shouldn't be on a brick background? It should be only on like white drywall?

Comment: @Dro Open another report! :P

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We don't accept bug reports that pertain to our walls, unless you happen to be in one of our offices and actually *see* a bug on a wall. At that point, you're welcome to ask if said bug belongs to anyone (we all love pets) and if not, help it find a new lease on life outside.

Comment: LOL "we all love pets" - do you pet bugs?

Comment: Why not use bug spray to remove it?

Comment: But hey, you never know if I actually *haven't been* in your offices. I'm a feature that visited you quite a number of times.

Comment: [You _do_ accept them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232216/179419), you just don't do anything about it (apart from knock the building down apparently) :-)

Comment: ^ o.0 so something *has changed*?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards That's a window, totally different.

Comment: The window is a wall, technically. With `background-color:transparent`.

Comment: @nicael Yes, I've kept ants and cockroaches as pets in terrariums built specifically to observe them as 'naturally' as possible. Conclusion: If cockroaches actually teamed up like ants do, we'd be really, really unlucky.

Comment: @TimPost why? An army of cockroaches fighting everything to steal your lunch?

Comment: @nicael early versions of IE doesn't support it. So we still end up with a solid wall that is opaque :P

Comment: @Uni The window *is* a solid wall, isn't it? ;)

Comment: and... 35th gold badge!