# Should Jeff Atwood's question about downvote weight be unlocked?

Tags: discussion, locked-questions, locked-votes

The question in question: [Should the weight of downvotes be increased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7322)

I have read [Why was this question about increasing downvote weight locked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298422) which says it was probably locked due to an abusive edit, via a mechanism that no longer exists (a fixed [bug with rollbacks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6368)).

The Q & A seems like a valid discussion still relevant to the network today, which people might like to vote on, at least. Maybe there is merit in being able to maintain the content as well. The lock prevents these things, for a reason that is neither visible nor relevant today.

A number of questions have been closed as a duplicate of Jeff's question. Ending up at a question from a co-founder of the network that is locked without obvious reason is a slightly odd experience.

A similar question [Should we have a policy about "too much downvoting"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42601) by the same author of roughly the same vintage is not locked.

This question isn't about what should happen to the Q & A aside from it potentially being unlocked.

Comment: I don't see why it should remain locked. At the same time I don't see any clear advantages to unlocking either.

Comment: @Luuklag it allows people to express their opinions on wether downvote weight should be increased.

Comment: @EkadhSingh they could do so now as well, they just have to make a new question.

Comment: @Luuklag ... that will get closed as a duplicate of a locked question 

Comment: @ErikDarling not when worded propperly. One should acknowledge the post, and all arguments made there, and state their arguments on why things would turn out better if changes were made.

Comment: @Luuklag "*I don't see any clear advantages to unlocking*" - one advantage is that it avoids all of this unnecessary work: "*One should acknowledge the post, and all arguments made there, and state their arguments on why things would turn out better if changes were made*" (especially if someone agrees with an existing answer as stated)

Comment: @Luuklag the SE network is (was?) all about reducing or minimizing "noise", so why would the right option be to ask the same question again?

Comment: @Luuklag but at the heart of things, it's *still a duplicate*. No one would stand for that elsewhere on the network, saying that asking duplicate questions is okay as long as you acknowledge the other ones.

Comment: Well there's no harm in trying... If anyone messes this up we can always lock it again.

Comment: [tag:status-completed]?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question [Should the weight of downvotes be increased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased) appears to have already been unlocked by @Tinkeringbell, [presumably as a result of this Meta SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366520/should-jeff-atwoods-question-about-downvote-weight-be-unlocked/366551?noredirect=1#comment1221267_366520), and about two hours after it was posted.

I think that is the correct action to have taken.